# Ensure multiple steps work/saving multiple models via a service

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails

I just thought of something new re: saving multiple objects in Rails (though Rails is not necessary).

Objectives:

- Create an author and a tomato, but both of those must be valid.
- If invalid creation, then return an error object.
- Not raise an `ActiveRecord` if I can (slow). (Is this something that I am even supposed to think about or am I overkilling this?)
- Make it easy to add steps/add steps in front or in the back.

That is just something I thought of. I just made creating authors and tomatoes methods that are sequentially called and checked if they are `valid?` or not.

I'm not sure what design pattern this is because the alternative is multiple `if` statements. If there is a formal gem or better way then I'd appreciate suggestions:

```
class AuthorAndTomatoSave
  def call
    steps.map do |step|
      result = step.call

      # If error, return
      return result unless result.valid?
    end

    # hypothetical case where we want to return the author. 
    # (this is also why create_author is memoized)
    create_author
  end

  private

  def steps
    [ proc { create_author }, proc { create_tomato } ]
  end

  def create_author
    @created_author ||= Author.create(author_params)
  end

  def create_tomato
    Tomoto.create(tomato_params)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues I see here:

- What happens if an `Author` is saved, and then `Tomato` creation fails? Should the author record remain in the database? (In most cases the answer would be no)
- How does a caller differentiate between a successful call and a failure to save an `Author`? In both cases, `call` returns an `Author` object. Would they have to always call `author.valid?` to check?

> Not raise an ActiveRecord if I can (slow). (Is this something that I am even supposed to think about or am I overkilling this?)

- This seems like a micro-optimization to me, I'd use whatever makes code easier to read.

The generic pattern to handle such cases is to use a [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). Transactions aren't specific to Rails, they are a feature that most databases offer. `ActiveRecord` [supports transactions out of the box](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).

In your case, this would be reduced to

```
def create_author_and_tomato!
  ActiveRecord::Transaction.do
    Tomato.create!(tomato_params)
    Author.create!(author_params)
  end
end
```

If any of those steps fail, the transaction will be rolled back (i.e. all databases changes reversed) before an exception is raised. Also, the `Author` object is returned if everything succeeds.

If you need to perform a different action if saving one record fails, catch the `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception.

```
begin
  author = create_author_and_tomato!

  # Use `author` for whatever
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  # `e.record` can be used to access the invalid object
end
```